# Chop series to build columns of dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, series

Sometimes I get a series where segments (all of equal length) of it belong together. In this cases, I need to chop up the series and arrange the segments into columns of a dataframe. For example, the series is of length 30 and I would like to make a dataframe with three columns, where each column is composed of the first, second, and last 10 entries of the series, respectively.

I use the code below which is a for-loop grabbing each chunk of the series and appending it as a column to the dataframe. The problem, is that is quite slow due to the for-loop. Is there a better way to do it in Pandas?

```
def series_to_dataframe(series,length,interval_length):
    #function to convert series to dataframe such that entries
    #within [k, k+interval_length], k % interval_length == 0, are mapped to a column
  
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,interval_length+1))

    for k in range(0, len(series), interval_length):
        df[k] = pd.Series(series.iloc[k : k + interval_length,0].reset_index()[0])
       
    return df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's slowing your code down is the construction and repeated modification of the data frame. Constructing a dictionary from the series and then the data frame from that dict:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({k: series[k*interval_length:(k+1)*interval_length].array for k in range(len(series)//interval_length)})
```

I was not able to compare the timing to your function because it raises an Error when given a Series.

Comment: Interesting point. Indeed, divide up the series ahead of time and then generate one dataframe. That might help. I'll check out the timing.

Comment: You could also make the Series a DataFrame, introduce a dummy column that contains the column index and use `.pivot` but somehow I would wish for that being slower as it involves redundant information storing. :D

Comment: Your initial response did it. I checked the timings and comes out 15 times faster than my loop. Thanks!